# Message in the terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

Well, i recently uninstall Oracle SQL developer... since that, when I open a terminal it shows me this:

```
bash: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/nls_lang.sh: No such file or directory
```

And I don't know how to remove it. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Do `grep -n 'nls_lang' ~/.bashrc ` in terminal. It probably put a config line there.

Comment: still appearing :(

Comment: What did `grep` command tell you, first of all ?

Comment: 120:export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`

Comment: Very well. Hold on a minute, will write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As solved in the comments via checking your `~/.bashrc` file via `grep -n 'nls_lang' ~/.bashrc`, there's

```
export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
```

segment on the line 120.  Simply remove that line or comment out, and the error won't appear again.

The backticks are a form of [command-substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html), so this expands `$ORACLE_HOME` to specific directory, concatenates it with `/bin/nls_lang.sh`. and executes that script. The output of that script should have been saved to `NLS_LANG` variable, and exported for use when that software is called from command line. In general, `export` makes variables available to whatever process shell starts.

As you have uninstalled the software, so the `nls_lang.sh` is also gone, but your `~/.bashrc` file has remained unchanged. Since `bash` reads `~/.bashrc` whenever you open interactive session in terminal, it still tries to execute that non-existing script, and that's why you see the error. What you should do, is go through `~/.bashrc` and probably remove the related variables such as `$ORACLE_HOME` and others.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. Thank you so much for your help. Peace!